# Transit through the UK as a Kenyan citizen with a valid USA B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, uk, transit, kenyan-citizens

Can I transit through the UK without a visa en route to USA as a Kenyan citizen with a valid USA B1/B2 visa?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica It does, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome!